# Python character alias to function

Tags: python, function, character, alias

Is there a way to associate the character '√' to actually perform the sqrt() function in python?

```
from math import sqrt

print sqrt(9)
>>> 3.0

print √9
>>> 3.0
```

Comment: I don't, I'm just asking for knowledge.

Comment: Well, I haven't yet heard of any programming language implementing that (NOT even programming languages for special purposes in science, business etc. like `R`, `Mathematica` etc. Probably because these symbols have to be typed from an image based keyboard. Then that will be like operating a calculator. Standard keyboards are better to do this job. :) Just write `sqrt(9)`. Why go into unnecessary symbol fuss?! Perhaps in future, when symbolic keyboards or touch screen keyboard will invade programming space, we will think about it.

Comment: I was simply wondering because I have a keyboard which permits such symbols easily: √∛≈²³⁸⁷≠± and thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Caker - That sounds like an interesting keyboard. Is it publicly available? Does it have a manufacturer and/or model name?

Comment: I configured it that way, it's not a physical keyboard. I created a deadkey which supports some greek symbols and mathematics symbols.